Angular: property binding with the property name constructed inside the loop
I have multiple properties:
tier1_eligibility: FormControl<boolean>;
tier2_eligibility: FormControl<boolean>;
tier3_eligibility: FormControl<boolean>;

which I want to bind to checkboxes. How can I do this with ngFor? I tried:
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let tier of [1,2,3]"
      [formControl]="myForm.controls.tier{{tier}}_eligibility"    <- Problem here !!
></mat-checkbox>

But it's not working - it's a problem of replacing {{tier}} with the appropriate number. What would be the appropriate syntax for this?

tiers_eligibility: FormControl<boolean>[]?

The question is can I bind it if I have a different properties (not an array) or such syntax does not exist?

Assume that the <mat-checkbox> is wrapped in a FormGroup, you can formControlName instead of [formControl].
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-checkbox 
    *ngFor="let tier of [1,2,3]"
    formControlName="tier{{tier}}_eligibility">
  </mat-checkbox>
</form>

Demo @ StackBlitz
